# Sane way to roll git master branch back in time + and then merge some files from a branch based on current master?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

(I'm afraid my search-fu is lacking, I didn't find answers to this specific scenario)

So, I have a git repo that looks like this:

```
   A a'', b''
   |
  /
 M a',b'
 |
 |
 |
 o a, b
 |
```

M is a current `master`, and A is a topic branch. `o` is an old commit, `a,b, etc` refer to the states of two particular set of files in the repo.

I've realized that I want to move `master` back in time to the commit `o` (files `a`), *except* for some particular files (`b''`) created / modified in topic branch `A`.  In other words, I want the new master to look like this:

```
M' a, b''
|
```

What would be the best way to do this?

(The one option I could do would be copy the files `b` to somewhere outside of the repo, roll the master back in time, and then just re-add those files like they were totally new commits. However, that doesn't sound like a very 'git' way of doing things.)

I also have an remote repo. I can `rebase` and `push --force` things, but I'd rather not; while not critical, I'd like the history to look 'nice' and pullable.

Comment: Is this repository a shared repository with sevral other clones (coworkers, public open source project ... ), or a repo with only one or two clones ?

Comment: It's a private repo with a couple of clones, but they're all mine (desktop + laptop(s) ).

Comment: However, I'm *also* interested in what I should do if the repository were more public (multiple people working on it etc).

Comment: If your changes are published, and shared on a public repo, you are better off leaving the current hostory as is, and adding commits on top of them. As if you were publishing some errata pages to ship along with a printed book.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the commit you want to base things on:

`git checkout desired-master`

Create a new branch:

`git checkout -b files-to-save`

Bring across the state of those files from the undesirable master:

```
git checkout master path/to/file/a
git checkout master path/to/file/b
```

Commit those changes, and then rebase them onto the desired master.

`git rebase desired-master files-to-save`

You will have to force push to achieve the "clean" history that you want for the master branch. This is not usually desirable but is possible - you'll need to communicate this before you do it to everyone else on the team, and you may need to make changes to your CI tool if you're using one.

Answer (score 1):

**Without changing the history of master**

From your current master, get back the version you wish for file `a` :

```
git checkout o -- a # 'o' is the commit reference, 'a' is the filename
```

Commit this :

```
git add a
git commit -m 'reverting file a to a previous correct version'
```

Get the version you wish for file `b`, from branch `A` :

```
git checkout A -- b
git add b
git commit -m 'integrating changes from branch A on file b'
```

**Changing the history of master**

For some reason, you may wish to 'erase' the erroneous history between `o` and `master`.

First : be safe and keep a reference to your current master :

```
git branch backup/master master
```

This will create a new branch `backup/master`, which points to the same commit as your current `master`.

If you have some modified files, store the changes somehow : aither `git stash` (quick to run, but easy to forget) or add the changes and commit them to `backup/master` (more visible in your history).

From your `master` branch, roll back to the commit `o` :

```
git checkout master # just to be sure you are acting on master
git reset --hard o # warning : if you have modified files, this is one of
                   # the few git commands which will throw away the
                   # changes with no way to get them back
```

Get the modifications you wish from `A` :

```
git checkout A -- b
git add b
git commit -m 'integrating changes from branch A on file b'
```

**Keeping the history from A**

Instead of just running `git checkout A -- b` (get the file's exact content, but do not keep the history), to can use `git rebase` to keep a track of the history `master--A` :

```
git checkout A
git branch backup/A # keep an easy way to undo your changes !
git rebase master
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's generally bad to change history on a "published" branch such as master.  Second, you're not working with file-sets, but change sets.   Instead of changing history, you can revert all the commits between 'o' and 'M', and then copy the contents of `b''` over to your "clean" master.